# Cilium pods stuck in Terminating state when running helm delete

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, kubernetes-pod, cilium

I have cilium installed in my test cluster (AWS, with the AWS CNI deleted because we use the cilium CNI plugin) and whenever I delete the cilium namespace (or run `helm delete`), the `hubble-ui` pod gets stuck in terminating state. The pod has a couple of containers, but I notice that one container named backend exits with code 137 when the namespace is deleted, leaving the hubble-ui pod and the namespace that the pod is in, stuck in `Terminating` state. From what I am reading online, containers exit with 137 when they attempt to use more memory that they have been allocated. In my test cluster, no resource limits have been defined (`spec.containers.[*].resources = {}`) on the pod or namespace. There is no error message displayed as reason for the error. I am using the cilium helm package v1.12.3, but this issue has been going on even before we updated the helm package version.

I would like to know what is causing this issue as it is breaking my CI pipeline.
How can I ensure a graceful exit of the backend container? (as opposed to clearing finalizers).

Answer (score 0):

So it appears that there is a bug in the `backend` application/container for the `hubble-ui` service. Kubernetes sends a `SIGTERM` signal to the container and it fails to respond. I verified this by getting a shell into the container and sending `SIGTERM` and `SIGINT`, which is what [the application seems to listen for](https://github.com/cilium/hubble-ui/blob/f032160be3cb5445bc1329777e0f0457271adffa/backend/main.go#L58) in order to exit and it just doesn’t respond to either signal.

Next, I added a `preStop` hook that looks like below and the pod behaved  itself

```
...
        lifecycle:
          preStop:
            exec:
              command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "kill -SIGILL 1; true"]
```